# using PySimpleGUI to make a video player but image can't show on the window and also crash

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, user-interface, pysimplegui

Problem occured when I run my code the image doesn't update in the window

I have searched for both the documentation of pysimplegui and opencv that mentioned video player  but still can't fix my problem : ( .

(use window 11 , anaconda virtual env, python 3)

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import cv2 as cv 
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np

sg.theme('Dark Blue 3')

file_types = [("JPEG (*.jpg)", "*.jpg"),
              ("All files (*.*)", "*.*")]


def gain_dimension(image):
    dim = image.shape
    h = image.shape[0]
    w = image.shape[1]
    print('Image Dimension    : ',dim)
    print('Image Height       : ',h)
    print('Image Width        : ',w)
    
    return 0
    

def main():
    read_layout = [      
             [sg.Text("video_file_path"),sg.InputText(key='-input_file-', enable_events=True),
              sg.FileBrowse('FileBrowse', key='-file-', target="-input_file-",)],
             [sg.Button('Read',key='-Read-'),sg.Cancel()]
    ]
             
    preview_video = [[sg.Image(filename='', expand_x=True, expand_y=True,  key='-preview_video-')]]
    
    layout_tot= [[sg.Frame(title='Read',layout = read_layout)],
                 [sg.Frame(title='preview_video',layout = preview_video)]]
    
    window = sg.Window('lab project',layout_tot,location=(10, 10),alpha_channel=1.0,
                                no_titlebar=False,resizable=True, grab_anywhere=False).Finalize()    

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == "exit":
            break
        elif event == "-Read-":
            read_path1 = Path(values['-input_file-'])
            
            if os.path.exists(read_path1):
                print(values["-input_file-"])
                cap = cv.VideoCapture(str(read_path1))
                
                if not cap.isOpened():
                    print("Cannot open video")
                    exit()
                
                while cap.isOpened():
                    (ret, frame) = cap.read()
                    if not ret:
                        print("Can't receive frame ,Exiting ...")
                        break
                    imgbytes = cv.imencode('.png', frame)[1].tobytes()
                    window['-preview_video-'].update(data=imgbytes)
            
    window.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I think the wrong place may be in the below two line since code before them work well

```
imgbytes = cv.imencode('.png', frame)[1].tobytes() 
window['-preview_video-'].update(data=imgbytes)
```

I want the video been read by cv.videocapture and use while loop to get frame by frame.
Since window['-preview_video-'].update(data=imgbytes) , the data type must be bytes or file so I convert them and try to update in my layout frame. However, it end up with crash .
pls help : (((

Comment: IMO, it is caused by the `while` loop - `while cap.isOpened():`. `window['-preview_video-'].update(data=imgbytes)` just update the element, not the GUI ! window refresh required. Try to call `window.refresh()` after you call `update` method of element. Better to do it on another thread and call `window.write_event_value` to generate event and value to event loop to update the Image element, or your GUI will be blocked there.

Comment: In addition to what Jason said the code as it is won't respect the frame rate of the video or any audio. Instead of implementing your own video player in python you might better embed a working video player like in this nice project https://github.com/israel-dryer/Media-Player

Comment: Have you looked at the PySimpleGUI Demo Program Demo_OpenCV.py?  It does exactly what you're describing (using `VideoCapture`, etc).